# Error while testing with H2 database with Reactive Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux, h2, r2dbc

I am using Reactive Spring boot to create a REST API and while the API works perfectly (I have tested it with postman), I also need to write some Unit tests and for the Unit tests I need to use a seperate in-memory database for it. I am using H2 database for testing and a hosted Postgres DB for the actual application and while my application entities are being loaded successfully in the postgres DB, None of my tests are passing as I receieve the following error:

`Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS full_connection ( id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY , aa TEXT NOT NULL, fip TEXT NOT NULL, status TEXT, created_on TIMESTAMP, created_by TEXT, last_updated_on TIMESTAMP, last_updated_by TEXT ); nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

I am assuming the error is being thrown because of the id paramater which has the datatype BIGINT which the official documentation of H2 says is mapped to java.long.Long.

Here's my entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
@Table
public class FullConnection {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "AA", nullable = false)
    private String aa;

    @Column(name = "FIP", nullable = false)
    private String fip;

    private String status;

    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    private String createdBy;

    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedOn;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

}
```

Here's how I am initializing the data:

```
@Bean
    ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resource =
                new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource(dataInitializerName));
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(resource);
        return initializer;
    }
```

where it's reading the dataInitializerName string from application-test.yaml and is being read correctly, the script (for testing)(the script for prod and testing are different) is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS full_connection (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY ,
    aa TEXT NOT NULL,
    fip TEXT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT,
    created_on TIMESTAMP,
    created_by TEXT,
    last_updated_on TIMESTAMP,
    last_updated_by TEXT
);
```

Here: https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#bigint_type it clearly states that BIGINT is mapped to java.long.Long, then why is it trying to cast it to int? Or is it regarding some other field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Explicitly defining the version for the dependency r2dbc-h2 in pom.xml is causing the problem. I removed the version so that springboot will automatically use the compatible version of r2dbc-h2, and then the problem resolved.